# How to invert the values of a specific color channel in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, texture, channel

I want to invert the green channel for my normal map texture (for use in a program which uses different handedness from the program that generated it). How do I do that using Photoshop preferably (or any other freeware program)? I believe CTRL + I or "Layer -> New Adjustment Layer -> Invert" inverts the color of all channels in the image. Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open **Window > Channels**

Select the Green channel and press CTRL + I to invert

Comment: When I select my Channel , ctrl+I does not work, and 'Image => adjustment=> invert' is greyed out.